# Full excel color list with xlsxwriter

Tags: python, colors, format, xlsxwriter

Is there a way to access the full range of colors that excel has using xlsxwriters workbook.add_format?

I have the following

```
cell_format1 = workbook.add_format({'bold':True,'align':'center','bg_color':'#217,217,217'})
```

In Excel the # 217, 217, and 217 refers to a light grey but the xlsxwriter is filling the cell in with black?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting from the `xlsxwriter` [docs](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_colors.html#colors):

> Throughout XlsxWriter colors are specified using a Html style #RRGGBB value.

So your 217, 217, 217 RGB color should be formatted as hex `#D9D9D9` (I googled and used the first online tool I found to do the conversion):

```
cell_format1 = workbook.add_format(
    {'bold':True, 'align':'center', 'bg_color':'#D9D9D9'}
)
```

Comment: You're welcome. If you google "rgb to hex" you'll find many tools to do any further color conversion you need.